# Having a problem retreiving data from cloud store flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

getting some errors when trying to retrieve from cloud store, I just can not work it out I hope someone can help as it's driving me mad

there are the two errors I am getting.

1st error >The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
2nd error
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: _db
                .collection("users")
                .doc(user.uid)
                .collection("tasks")
                .orderBy("date", descending: true)
                .snapshots(), 
           builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                if (snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                  return ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((snap) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(snap.data["tasks"]),
                        onTap: () {},
                        trailing: IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _db
                                .collection("users")
                                .doc(user.uid)
                                .collection("tasks")
                                .doc(snap.id)
                                .delete();
                          } ,
                          
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
                } else {
                  // ignore: avoid_unnecessary_containers
                  return Container(
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/no_task.png")),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }
            })
```

Comment: You no longer need `snap.data["tasks"]`, but can nowadays simply do `snap["tasks"]`. See the questions I linked for more. I highly recommend [searching for your error messages](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+operator+%27%5B%5D%27+isn%27t+defined+for+the+type+%27Object?+Function()%27.+Try+defining+the+operator+%27%5B%5D%27+site:stackoverflow.com) going forward btw, as that's how I found these solutions.

Comment: wow thankyou that solution worked but i still can not get ri of the first error :/ I have searched and searched?

Comment: You're missing an `else` somewhere, and in that case your builder is not rendering any widget. I recommend removing that final `else` and just having a top-level, default `return Container(....)` at the end of your builder to ensure you always render a widget.

Comment: Thankyou mate , I got it working but faced with another error now about 'user' doesn't excist lol I dont have anything called user only 'users' something to do with databases  it never ends